# When serving a static webpage with backblaze-b2 and cloudflare, how to get domain to appear instead of bucket origin?

Tags: cloudflare, backblaze

I am following backblaze's instructions to [serve a static webpage through cloudflare](https://www.backblaze.com/docs/cloud-storage-deliver-public-backblaze-b2-content-through-cloudflare-cdn#locate-your-bucket-origin).

Part of this involves creating a cloudflare 'page rule' which directs from the domain to the backblaze bucket, for example the forwarding rule:

```
example.com -> https://f000.backblazeb2.com/file/example-bucket/index.html
```

This works to serve the page. The one problem I have is with the url that appears in the browser's address bar. Instead of `example.com` it shows `f000.backblazeb2.com/file/example-bucket/index.html`. Is there a cloudflare page rule that can serve the backblaze bucket while keeping the original domain appearing in the browser's address bar?

---

UPDATE:

I found that with a 'Forwarding URL' page rule with origin URL `https://example.com/` and destination URL `https://example.com/file/example-bucket/index.html`, then when navigating to `example.com` the browser will at least display `example.com/file/example-bucket/index.html` in the address bar. This at least verifies to the user that what they are looking at is under the intended domain. It would still be good to have just the domain appear without the following `/file/example-bucket/`, as that is not relevant to the organization of the site, only to the bucket in which the content is stored. Is there a way to get something more like `example.com/index.html` from `example.com/file/example-bucket/index.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a [Forwarding URL](https://developers.cloudflare.com/support/page-rules/understanding-and-configuring-cloudflare-page-rules-page-rules-tutorial/#:%7E:text=All-,Forwarding%20URL,-Redirects%20one%20URL) page rule is triggered, Cloudflare returns a `302 Found` (aka redirect) HTTP status code with the `Location` header set to the URL you specify, rather than proxying the request to the origin. Hence you were originally seeing the browser loading the `https://f000.backblazeb2.com/file/example-bucket/index.html` page.

Rather than a Forwarding URL page rule, you need a [Transform Rule](https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/), specifically a [Rewrite URL rule](https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/transform/url-rewrite/), so that Cloudflare *rewrites* the URL before proxying the request to the origin.

In your Cloudflare domain:

1. Navigate to **Rules** > **Transform Rules**.
2. Click **Create Rule**.
3. Give the rule a descriptive name, e.g. "Rewrite root to index".
4. Under **When incoming requests match…**, Click **Custom filter expression**.
5. Set **Field** to "URI Full", **Operator** to "equals", and **Value** to the root of your domain, e.g. `https://example.com/`.
6. Under **Set Rewrite parameters** > **Path**, Click *Rewrite to...*.
7. Select **Static** and enter the target path, without the leading '/', e.g. `file/example-bucket/index.html`.
8. Click **Deploy**.

Now, when the incoming URL matches `https://example.com/`, Cloudflare rewrites the path to `file/example-bucket/index.html`, so it requests `https://f000.backblazeb2.com/file/example-bucket/index.html` from the origin, but the URL in the browser will remain `https://example.com/`.